# Additional chat one-boxing for Google Play and App Store

Tags: discussion, feature-request, onebox

I've noticed in chat that Google Play apps and iOS App Store apps don't get oneboxed. I feel like these would be good candidates for oneboxing, as things like tweets and Amazon items get one boxed, so why not apps?